# Regex not matching when start end specified

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following regex expression in PHP

```
/^(\d{4}-(\d{4})?)$/
```

I want match only a string like this

```
1998-
1998-2015
```

I am using it in laravel validation like so:

```
'release_year' => 'required|regex:/^(\d{4}-(\d{4})?)$/'
```

Nothing else should match and number should be a 4 digit number. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It is working. Add multiline flag in the demo. You must check the regex in code, not just on the regex demo site.

Comment: Try `$rules = array('release_year' => array('required|"match:/^([0-9]{4}-([0-9]{4})?)$/"'));`.

Comment: `Method [validate"match] does not exist.`

Comment: still same error: `Method [validate"match] does not exist.`

Comment: This worked for someone before: `$rules = array(
    'release_year' => array(
        'required',
        'Regex:/^([0-9]{4}-([0-9]{4})?)$/'
    ) 
);`, please check.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel documentation:

> `regex:pattern`
>
> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify
>   rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the
>   regular expression contains a pipe character.

Try this:

```
'release_year' => array('required', 'regex:/^(\d{4}-(\d{4})?)$/')
```